# Android proguard nightmare

Tags: android, proguard

When I build a new APK for my app, the old serialized saved data does not load anymore, I get this exception:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.myapp.b.b; Incompatible class (SUID): org.myapp.b.b: static final long serialVersionUID =1L; but expected org.myapp.b.b: static final long serialVersionUID =0L;
```

I have this in proguard.cfg:

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    !private <fields>;
    !private <methods>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

My serialVersionUID is unchanged in the code.  When I debug, everything works, but when I test my new apk, it wont load the old data.

ANy ideas?

Comment: http://littlepancake.com/2011/09/proguard-and-serialized-java-objects/ ?

Comment: thanks, i actually tried that to no avail.

Comment: You tried setting your class' `serialVersionUID` to `0` and that _didn't_ work?

Comment: yes i have tried that as well, 0L

Comment: no one else?  this has to be a common proguard issue

Comment: Have you used the same configuration for your previous release?

Comment: what do you mean configuration?  everything is the same, the only difference is the apk version.  this is really weird.

Comment: hi, did you solve this problem yourself? normally, if you have the recommended generic set of proguard rules[https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#serializable] for both old and new versions of the app, data should be loaded without any problem. Please let me know your response as I am in the process of uploading a new app with Serializable classes used for data storage.